# Decimal and double values are resolving to zero

Tags: c#

I am expecting weight value to be 0.153846 in the code below. Instead I am getting 0.  I tried using double and decimal.  period is 10

```
public static Deque<DateClose> EMAMethod(
    Queue<DateClose> queue,
    Deque<DateClose> firstEMASample, 
    int period)
{
    double weight = (2/(period+1));

    Deque<DateClose> sample = new Deque<DateClose>(firstEMASample.ToArray());
    Deque<DateClose> expoMovingAverageQueue = new Deque<DateClose>(queue.Count() + 1);

    // get the last item or initial MA value from the queue
    DateClose eMA = sample.RemoveFromBack();
```

The is indeed a duplicate.  I did search but did not find this answer.

Comment: try `double weight = (2.0/(period+1.0));`

Comment: `double weight = (2d/(period+1));` otherwise, the calculation is performed as `int` then converted to `double`, resulting in truncation.

Comment: When you say " I am dividing one double and one integer", which exact operation are you referring to? In C#, a literal `2` gets you an **`int`** ...

Comment: AakashM, I was wrong, there are two integers.  I did not realize that.